# Ubuntu 16.04 booting to black screen with blinking cursor when adding additional hard drives

Tags: boot, server, grub2, partitioning, lvm

I recently updated my home Server to 16.04, undeniably the worst decision as I did not do it properly and just updated without backing up. Save all of the comments of back ups and what have you.
I have googled this though nothing similar comes up, i searched what i could and still nothing, as my knowledge on this area is slim, but here is  the res...
I have an LVM across three complete HDDs and partially formatted on the same drive my root is and swap. Three out of four disks are completely formatted for LVM while the This looks like this:

- sda:

  - sda1: 782GB LVM
- sdb:

  - sdb1: 250GB LVM
- sdc:

  - sdc3: 32GB LVM
  - sdc1: 32GB / ext4
  - sdc5: 16GB swap
- sdd:

  - sdd1: 250GB LVM
- sde:

  - sde1: 250GB LVM

The LVM has about 200/250 GB of movies and shows I would like to keep them on there if at all possible.
Whenever I have the additional drives physically connected the computer boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor and will not let me do anything as after a few keystrokes the machine makes the invalid stroke beeping noise.
When the rest are removed it boots to GRUB and loads normally and works peachy, I have looked up hot swapping my drives, but am a little skeptical about trying that.
This is a home server, everything I've done is based off questions others have asked as well as tutorials, I do look a lot of things up, which is probably why I did not know of the precautions when upgrading. ALSO this is not a dual boot, IT is running off an HP machine, but the HDDs are clean of an OS save the one running UBUNTU 16.04

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS boot settings to see if it's still pointing to the right harddrive?

Comment: @Jeremy I have tried and the only options when configuring boot order are: USB, Network, Hard Drive: (Integrated SATA) I thought that might have been an issue but I can't seem to change it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my problem is semi-unrelated to UBUNTU, Semi because the problem did not exist until i Updated my server to 16.04, but the fix was hardware. After I re installed ubuntu 16.04 twice on my root partition, loosing all the setup I had prior, I learned that some desktops will force SATA0 to be the default OS drive even if one is not located there, I realized this when I booted up the system with all drives mounted that BIOS told me the HDD boot drive order and the one with ROOT was second. After switching the cables around everything seems to be in order. I just mounted the rest of the drives, nothing lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms after upgrading to 16.04.

In my case it turned out to be a portable USB device was the issue.

Linux must have been attempting to boot from my USB back up. Unplugging the device and forcing a restart fixed the issue.