# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS no boot no disk activity. Black Screen with typeable cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

so it happened after yesterday, when I had to force Shutdown Ubuntu(by pressing the power button) after it would not shutdown/Restart by selecting the option from the menu at the top right, or even by the terminal `sudo shutdown now` or `reboot`. Before this happened it was on a suspend/resume schedule for about 10 days.
Now, when I Try to start Ubuntu from the Grub menu, after selecting the options, there is no disk activity. Just a black screen with a cursor, which you can type on.

Answers I have referred: 
[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776150/ubuntu-16-04-booting-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-when-adding-additional)
[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315246/first-boot-after-ubuntu-install-blank-screen-w-responsive-cursor)

But, to no avail.

Things I have tried:

1. Booting with another Kernel version.
2. Boot repair
3. disk SMART details: Disk is OK.
4. Smart Details
   [SMART Details](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1unpBUAFHxeYjU3VFh1WFBzOGM/view?usp=sharing)

OK, I figured it out. I booted in safe mode and checked the disk in the option menu given on the screen. It said that the swap partition could not be found. I had deleted the swap partition and made a new one. So I edited the swap entry in the /etc/fstab with the UUID of the new partition.

**It still doesn't boot. but doesn't give any error in safe mode disk check.**

Comment: both of your links point to the same question which has no answers. did you look at the question that is was linked to? Possible duplicat of https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @ravery I did have a look at that answer. I have a dual boot system, and I have tried 2 of the 3 options. I do not want to remove Ubuntu. I looked at the other answers: I do not have an Nvidia Card. And I would really like to not reinstall. I have also installed the correct AMD/ATI Drivers (Open Source) about 13 days before this happened

Comment: did you turn secure boot off? Ubuntu kernels newer than 4.3 require signed modules

Comment: @ravery Yes Secure boot has been turned off. The Computer boots in UEFI using grubx64.efi

Comment: ok, in grub press "e" to edit the boot command. Change "quiet splash" to "nosplash", then F-10 to boot with the changes, look for errors

Comment: @ravery OK, I figured it out. I booted in safe mode and checked the disk in the option menu given on the screen. It said that the swap partition could not be found. I had deleted the swap partition and made a new one. So I edited the swap entry in the /etc/fstab with the UUID of the new partition. It still doesn't boot. but doesn't give any error in safe mode disk check.